# Array Of Drawable Images

Tags: android

Ok so first of I will take you through the basics of my App. So far you take picture using the camera which then gets saved into a folder. Once the picture has been took a new Activity opens and shows the picture on screen in a `ImageView`.

The effect I am trying to achive is something along the lines of being able to create png layers over the top of the picture in the `ImageView` with the onClick Event. So say I have 5 transparent png's I want to have five onClick events which with each touch of the screen a new png image will get displayed over the top of the picture in the `ImageView` so it would take 5 onClick (touch of screen) to show all the transparent png's over the top of the picture.

I think I am nearly there with the code below but I think I need to create an `array` of the images in the `drawable` folder that need to be displayed with each onClick event, I think the array should be `nextBitmap` but not to sure.

**Update Sparkys answer**

I have tried adding `private Integer[] nextBitmap = { R.drawable.img1, R.drawable.img2 };` but I am getting the error `The method getBitmapOverlay(Bitmap, Bitmap, int, int) in the type BeatEmUp is not applicable for the arguments (Bitmap, Integer[], int, int)` anyone know what this could be do I need to add the `private Integer[]......` outside the `onCreate` method?

```
public class Image extends Activity {

Bitmap myBitmap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.Image);

    String myRef = this.getIntent().getStringExtra("filepath");
    File imgFile = new  File(myRef);
    Log.e("No ref", myRef);

    if(imgFile.exists()) {
        final Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
        final ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.beatemup);
        myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
        myImage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                myBitmap = getBitmapOverlay(myBitmap, nextBitmap, 0, 0);
                myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
            }
        });
    }
}

public static Bitmap getBitmapOverlay(Bitmap bmp1, Bitmap bmp2, int left, int top) {
    Bitmap bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp1.getWidth(), bmp1.getHeight(),  bmp1.getConfig());
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmOverlay);    
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp1, 0, 0, null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp2, left, top, null);
    return bmOverlay;
}
}
```

Comment: If the user has to click 5 times before the 5 images show, I wouldn't load them all in an array because the user might not click 5 times. It would be a waste of memory and battery power. I'd load them every time the user clicks.

Comment: Ok cool, not sure how to do that though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I have made you a small working sample that might be what you are looking for.

I break my own rules here because I did code for you. As I know that you are a beginner, you **should definitively understand the following code before you use it**.

```
public class Image extends Activity {

    Bitmap myBitmap;
    Integer[] mBitmapIds = new Integer[] { R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher };
    Random mRand = new Random();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        final ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview);
        myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
        myImage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            int i = 0;

            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (i >= mBitmapIds.length) {
                    i = 0;
                }
                myImage.setImageBitmap(getBitmapOverlay(myBitmap, BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), mBitmapIds[i]), 0, 0));
            }
        });
    }

    public Bitmap getBitmapOverlay(Bitmap bmp1, Bitmap bmp2, int left, int top) {
        Bitmap bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp1.getWidth(),
                bmp1.getHeight(), bmp1.getConfig());
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmOverlay);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp1, 0, 0, null);
        left += mRand.nextInt(20);
        top += mRand.nextInt(20);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp2, left, top, null);
        return bmOverlay;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See the [Hello, Views tutorial, GridView chapter](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html) for an example of an array of references to Drawables.

Comment: Ok so it would be something like `private Integer[] nextBitmap = { R.drawable.img1, R.drawable.img2, };` when i try this though I get the error `The method getBitmapOverlay(Bitmap, Bitmap, int, int) in the type BeatEmUp is not applicable for the arguments (Bitmap, Integer[], int, int)`